# Memory consumption on Windows Phone 8 is 3 times what is on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, memory-consumption

I'm developing an app that runs on both WP7 and WP8. After I finished it I started running the Performance analysis to improve the app overall performance.

The app is written for WP7, but I have some projects that run over WP8 to add features like in-app-purchase, lockscreen and so on.

When I ran the memory analysis on WP7, the app averaged 50mb of ram throughout execution, an acceptable value, the weird thing was when I ran the same xap on a WP8 device the app uses on average 150mb of ram.

I searched around the web and found nothing related to this issue.

I used a Lumia 800 and lumia 510 to make the analysis on the WP7., and use a Lumia 520, 820 and 925 to make the analysis on WP8 devices.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

I also considered that it could be a bug on VS2012, but the app crashes on the lumia 520 (with out of memory, after a while) but never crashes on the lumia 800 or 510.

The app is heavy on images, but all of them are the exact size that is used on the phone (never more than 50 100x100 jpg pictures are displayed in the app at the same time).

Any suggestions and solutions are welcome.

EDIT: The memory differences that I'm talking about is just by running the Home view, my performance analysis test is simply, launch the app swipe some controls (I have a pivot with 2 items) and close the session. There is no navigation involved. I'm using a RadDataboundListBox, but already tried to change to Listbox and LongListMultiSelector without any significant memory consumption change

Comment: Did you try the Memory Profiler (built in Visual Studio) ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj215908(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I did, the values that I gave on the question are from it ;)

Comment: I was asking that because the memory profiler indicates what objects are taking so much RAM. Is it the images?

Comment: The odd thing is that I see on the profiler an average usage of 150mb (on the graphs), but when I select one of those areas to make an analysis, the sum of total memory used is on average 80mbs (this really confuses me).
About what is using more memory, Initially I though it were the images, so I removed them, but the funny is that my listboxitems occupy more than 1mb even without any image...